# Llamar una función desde html

Tags: html

Necesito llamar a la funcion abcd que se encuentra en el JS y poder pasarle parámetro, el ejemplo acá esta sin parámetros ya que todavía no me funciona.

Mi HTML es asi

```
        <head>
        <title>ejemplo</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <script src="./barcode_sample.js"></script>     
        </head>
        
        <body>   
         <a href="javascript:abcd('864126673800090001785002019700232050202099')">link text</a> * Esta funciona
         <script> abcd();</script>  *Esta NO funciona
         <div id="result"></div>  
        </body>
        </html>
```

> Me da error : Uncaught ReferenceError: abcd is not defined. No tengo mucha experiencia en esto, una ayuda me vendría bien, gracias

Comment: El código JS está dentro de `barcode_sample.js` o dónde? Tratá de editar tu pregunta y poner un código funcional como ejemplo.

Comment: azeós, eso es todo lo que tiene, no se que mas agregar

Comment: ¿En qué momento querés ejecutar la funcion, al hacer un click, al cargar la pagina?

Comment: Esta función va ha ser llamada dentro de un loop en body usando Handlebars, idea es pasarle los parámetros correspondiente a la funcion abcd(),No voy a usar clic.

Comment: mira este enlace, tal vez este la respuesta que necesitas https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/plantillas-javascript-handlebars.html

Comment: Gracias jag,te cuento que no tengo problema en entender handelsbar, lo uso y me sirve para lo que lo uso. Sin duda hay algo que no veo, ya que sigue sin funcionar.